# Decryption Error : Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, rijndael

I used this code to decrypt my file, but I have receive this error:

> Decryption Error : Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

My code:

```
private void DecryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    //try
    //{
    string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here

    UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

    FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

    RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
        RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
        CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

    int data;
    while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
        fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

    fsOut.Close();
    cs.Close();
    fsCrypt.Close();

    //}
    //catch
    //{
    //    Label12.Text = "Decryption failed!";
    //}
}
```

It works good in c# application but I have error in asp.net pages!

Comment: debug your code step by step - there are too many answers for helping with this error - your code is not help to get any answer.

Comment: 1) Check the file you are trying to decrypt. Is it exactly the same as I uses with the console code.
2) The problem might be in the code that encrypt your file. Provide this code to this question.

Comment: error occurred in While loop

Comment: Post your encryption code as well.

Comment: Also try simply `cs.CopyTo(fsOut);` instead of your loop.

Comment: On what line do you get the exception `Decryption Error : Length of the data to decrypt is invalid`? Also show your encryption code, if that is wrong then this will never work. Finally consider always using `using` blocks for your disposable instances.

Comment: Check if you are able to read the file, using `File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);`. It might be permission issue which usually happens in ASP.NET. As you mentioned that this code is working in C# application (Console or WinForms) I think its permission issue only.